# Xcode - Test class File is part of module, ignoring import

Tags: ios, xcode

So I have an iOS project with tests and everything was working properly.

I felt the need to change the project name. I did as indicated at apple's docs, 
selected the project and changed its name.

After a while of updating things for this to finally work, the app runs ok, but I'm still having a problem.

I can't run the tests because of this annoying issue. I'm sure it's a basic thing, but still I can't quite figure it out.

Here's my test class (for the sake of the question I'm using a `Foo` example)

```
@testable import MyApp // File FooTests is part of module MyApp. Ignoring import.

class FooTests: QuickSpec {

  override func spec() {

     describe("a foo test") {
         it("tests foo") {
             let return = Foo.barMethod()
             XCTAssertEqual(return, "expected", "Expected something, got \(return) instead")
         }
    }
 }
```

The `Foo` class is not being recognized, and I get the error that the test class is part of `MyApp` which is not the case.

Where should I look for?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

I just stumbled on the same problem, and your post was helpful. What I found out is by change the `Product Name` to `AppNameTests`, as per your example, then the product module name is reflected correctly and you don't have to add `Tests` at the end of `$(PRODUCT_NAME:c99extidentifier)`. `c99extidentifier` seems torefers to `Product Name`.

Summary:

- select your test target in Project
- navigate to `Build Settings -> Packaging`
- change the `Product Name` to your previous test target, likely appending `Tests`
- I believe the rename as per [Apple's renaming a project](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/RenamingaProject/RenamingaProject.html) doesn't include the updating the module in `@testable`, so I had to do this manually

Comment: That's it! I was close. :) your answer is definitely cleaner. :)

Comment: Works like a charm. perfect answer.

Comment: Instead of manually changing the `Product Name` and appending `Tests`, just set the `Product Name` back to `$(TARGET_NAME)`. I've tested Xcode 8 beta 2, and renaming the project now solves this issue.

Comment: After impudently renaming my project, and applying this solution, i was fighting for a short time with "missing `TEST_HOST`". If you are **that** deep in xcodeproj custom changes, i recommend deleting your test target and creating it from scratch. Done in no time, all problems gone.

Comment: Check for Product Module Name too.

Answer (score 10):

**[UPTADE]** This helped Jean-Frederic figuring out his answer. That's why I accepted it.

I finally managed to fix this, but I'm not happy with the solution.

Consider my app name `AppName`

For some weird reason I cannot explain, my test target `Build Settings -> Product Module Name` had `$(PRODUCT_NAME:c99extidentifier)` which value was the `Appname`, instead of `AppNameTests`. I checked with other projects and the value is the same but converted to `AppNameTests` so in this case I'm not sure what I can do to make it automatically update and include the Test part in the name.

What I ended up doing was setting the name as `$(PRODUCT_NAME:c99extidentifier)Tests`. Not sure if this is a proper solution, but for now it works.

If anybody has a better solution, please feel free to share.

Answer (score 4):

This is a directly parallel solution to Jean-Frederic Plante, though in my case the problem was not that my test target name matched my primary target, but rather that the module of the test target had incorrectly been set to match the module name of the main app target. To correct either of these issues:

- Select your test target in your project.
- Navigate to *Build Settings* > *Packaging*.
- Ensure both the *Product Module Name* and *Product Name* are set to `$(TARGET_NAME)`.