# How can I import a Swift class into a XCTestCase Swift file?

Tags: objective-c, swift, unit-testing, cocoa-touch

There seems to be a few posts on this.

I believe they mention needing to do the following things:

1. In "Build Settings" > "Build Options", set "Enable Testability"
   to YES.
2. Grab the "Product Module Name" in "Target" > "Build
   Settings" > "Packaging".
3. List item

In your Swift XCTestCase file, as of
    Swift 2.x, use the "Product Module Name" obtained in step 2 as
    follows: `@testable import MyProductModuleName`

I have done all of these things, but cannot access any class of my project from my Swift XCTestCase Class. My "Product Module Name" is "My_App". So I have `@testable import My_App` at the top of my test class.

Despite doing a clean, and building, I cannot get the class to recognize anything.

iOS Deployment Target is 8.0. The majority 95% of the app is Obj-C, however this particular class I want to test is Swift, and the TestCase I've created is also Swift. I've also updated my Podfile to 8.0.

Comment: Does this answer help? Not positive from your description, but could be similar issue...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34889552/xcode-test-class-file-is-part-of-module-ignoring-import