# Xcode - File is part of module, ignoring import

Tags: ios, xcode, xctest

I have existing iOS project, added Unit test target and created new test case file in `tests` folder. When i tried to import module i'm facing this issue. I referred the below stack overflow question but it did not solve my problem.

[Xcode - Test class File is part of module, ignoring import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34889552/xcode-test-class-file-is-part-of-module-ignoring-import)

```
@testable import wl_pih // Error: File 'wl_pihTests.swifts' is part of module 'wl_pih'; ignoring import

class wl_pihTests: XCTestCase {

    let loginController = INCLoginViewController() //Not accessable
     override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
    }

    override func tearDown() {
              super.tearDown()
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please add your code as text so that it is searchable, instead of adding screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you that because your *test* file is in your `wl_pih` target, there's no need for the `@testable import wl_pih` statement. `@testable import` is used in test files that are in a *unit test* or *UI test* target to give them access to files in the target that you want to test. The easiest fix is to delete your import. What you *really* should do, though, is to put your test files in your *unit testing* target (so that they don't get bundled into your deliverable app), and leave the `@testable import` statement in each test file.

Comment: I've removed `import` statement, still not able to access files from wl_pih target. `test` file is added to test target. Checked for any test file in `wl_pih` target(Build phases -> Compile Sources) but i did not find anything. Please help.