# File 'ProjectTests.swift' is part of module 'Project'; ignoring import

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing

I'm trying to implement a unit test for my project. 
When I use :

```
@testable import Project
```

it says:

> "File 'ProjectTests.swift' is part of module 'Project'; ignoring
>   import". So I can't use project classes

I read similar questions and use all answers, but it gives no results.
Seems like I have some trouble: 
[Xcode - File is part of module, ignoring import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45870329/xcode-file-is-part-of-module-ignoring-import?noredirect=1&lq=1)

tried:

1. Check product module name in Project -> Build Settings -> Packaging
   -> Product Module Name. (it is same for sure)
2. Enable testability in Build Options
3. Make Legacy Build system
4. Target Membership is on Tests target(not project, and this is right)
5. Full clean Derive Data and project
6. copy content of project, delete all content, copy back.

Comment: I removed my answer as it did not solve the issue. I suggested making sure the file was part of the tests target, which it is.

Comment: Thx anyway for help=)